# how to create new state on the fly

Tags: reactjs

I have two components in my project.

One is App.jsx

One is Child.jsx

[image]

Right now inside, there are 3 child components was rendered manually. The presenting data in child was passed from parent.

However, in future, I would like to add a button that can create new child on the fly.

let say, I can see a new child 4 appear after child 3, after clicking a new button.

So,

Q1: First question, since presenting data must be from parent (as I dont want to losing data after condition changing from false to true), how could I write things like creating extra state on the fly?

Q2: Second question: How to create a new component after child 3, after clicking a add child button?

For better illustrate, here is my code https://playcode.io/940784

In App.jsx:

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import {Child} from './Child.jsx'
export function App(props) {

  [message,setMessage]=useState('');
  [showChild1,setShowChild1]=useState(true);
  [showChild2,setShowChild2]=useState(true);
  [showChild3,setShowChild3]=useState(true);

const [child1data,setChild1data] = useState('child1');
const [child2data,setChild2data] = useState('child2');
const [child3data,setChild3data] = useState('child3');

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('parent was rendered')
  })
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      

<button >add child</button>
<br/>
<br/>

<button onClick={()=>setShowChild1(!showChild1)}>Show child1</button>
{showChild1 && <Child key='1' data={child1data} setData={setChild1data}/>}
<br/>
<br/>
<button onClick={()=>setShowChild2(!showChild2)}>Show child2</button>
{showChild2 && <Child key='2'data={child2data} setData={setChild2data}/>}

<br/>
<br/>
<button onClick={()=>setShowChild3(!showChild3) } setData={setChild3data}>Show child3</button>
<br/>
{showChild3 && <Child key='3' data={child3data}/>}
      

    </div>
  );
}

// Log to console
console.log('Hello console')
```

In Child.jsx

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

export const Child = (props) => {

const {data,setData} = props;



useEffect(()=>{
  console.log(data)
})

  return <>
  
  <h1>This is {data}</h1>
  <input value={data} onChange={((e)=>setData(e.target.value))}></input>
  
  </>
}
```

Comment: when you are counting your variable, you should problably wrap it into an `array`. then you can use `.push()` to add an item

Comment: may I ask if I wrap them all into a array, then how to do the update on specific child data?

Comment: Do you need to access any of each child's state from the parent?

Comment: Yes, or I should say I want to pass the state from parent to child, and I dont want to create state in child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code snippet below, I've created an example demonstrating how to create, manage, and update an array of child state objects from a parent component. I've included lots of inline comments to help explain as you read the code:

> After you Run the code snippet, you can select "Full page" to expand the viewport area of the iframe.

```css
body, button, input { font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 1rem; } button, input { padding: 0.5rem; } ul { list-style: none; } .vertical { display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: flex-start; gap: 0.5rem; }
```

```html
<div id="root"></div><script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.18.12/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="env,react">

// import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
// import {StrictMode, useState} from 'react';

// This Stack Overflow snippet demo uses UMD modules
// instead of the commented import statments above
const {StrictMode, useState} = React;

// Returns a new child state object with a unique ID:
function getInitialChildState () {
  return {
    hidden: false,
    id: window.crypto.randomUUID(),
    text: '',
  };
}

// A child component that displays a text state and allows for
// modifying the text state using a controlled input:
function Child ({text, setText}) {
  return (
    <div className="vertical">
      <div>{text ? text : 'Empty '}</div>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={ev => setText(ev.target.value)}
        value={text}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

// A wrapper component for each child that allows toggling its "hidden" property
// and conditionally renders the child according to that value:
function ChildListItem ({state, updateState}) {
  const toggleHidden = () => updateState({hidden: !state.hidden});
  const setText = (text) => updateState({text});
  return (
    <li className="vertical">
      <button onClick={toggleHidden}>{
        state.hidden
          ? 'Show'
          : 'Hide'
      } child</button>
      {
        state.hidden
          ? null
          : <Child text={state.text} setText={setText} />
      }
    </li>
  );
}

function App () {
  // Array of child states:
  const [childStates, setChildStates] = useState([]);

  // Append a new child state to the end of the states array:
  const addChild = () => setChildStates(arr => [...arr, getInitialChildState()]);

  // Returns a function that allows updating a specific child's state
  // based on its ID:
  const createChildStateUpdateFn = (id) => (updatedChildState) => {
    setChildStates(states => {
      const childIndex = states.findIndex(state => state.id === id);
      // If the ID was not found, just return the original state (don't update):
      if (childIndex === -1) return states;
      // Create a shallow copy of the states array:
      const statesCopy = [...states];
      // Get an object reference to the targeted child state:
      const childState = statesCopy[childIndex];
      // Replace the child state object in the array copy with a NEW object
      // that includes all of the original properties and merges in all of the
      // updated properties:
      statesCopy[childIndex] = {...childState, ...updatedChildState};
      // Return the array copy of the child states:
      return statesCopy;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Parent</h1>
      <button onClick={addChild}>Add child</button>
      <ul className="vertical">
        {
          childStates.map(state => (
            <ChildListItem
              // Every list item needs a unique key:
              key={state.id}
              state={state}
              // Create a function for updating a child's state
              // without needing its ID:
              updateState={createChildStateUpdateFn(state.id)}
            />
          ))
        }
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

const reactRoot = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

reactRoot.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);

</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer, I am still thinking about it. One question first ,  "const createChildStateUpdateFn = (id) => (updatedChildState) =>. " , may I ask why there are two => there ? how to interprete it?

Comment: and I dont understand why in child component, we will pass an object in updateState function, is it directly pointing to createChildStateUpdateFn(state.id) ? So we should simply call it by updateState in child component? This part doesnt make sense to me.

Comment: @AeLeung In response to your [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73340134/how-to-create-new-state-on-the-fly/73346712?noredirect=1#comment129535801_73346712): An example probably illustrates best. This is a function  that returns true: `() => true`. This is a function that returns a function that returns true: `() => () => true`. The function is returning another function.

Comment: @AeLeung I’m sorry to say that I don’t understand your [second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73340134/how-to-create-new-state-on-the-fly/73346712?noredirect=1#comment129535868_73346712).

Comment: Thanks, I guess your first answer somehow actually answered my second question, but I have been doubt yet. May I ask, is it that writing a function that returns a function is what we want in general? Becasue to me it sounds a bit counter intrutive. I understand it works in this case, but if it is better if we use a style of eg: " const tmp = () => {} .... instead of tmp = () => () => {} ? But I dont know if it is still doable in this situation.

Comment: @AeLeung I'm still not sure that I understand your question... are you just wanting more intermediate variable names? Rather than using a made-up example like `tmp = () => () => {}`, perhaps you can refer to the actual syntax in the code for more clarity.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I mean 
instead of wrting like this: const createChildStateUpdateFn = (id) => (updatedChildState) => {} 
Could we do const createChildStateUpdateFn = (updatedChildState) => {}

Comment: Because , to me, () => () => {}  seems a bit weird. But I am not sure if it make sense to write things like this. Coz I  am new to react

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73340134/how-to-create-new-state-on-the-fly/73346712?noredirect=1#comment129542211_73346712) @AeLeung Thanks, I understand now. The answer is: no, the `id` parameter is required to target the specific child state object that should be updated: it can't just be omitted.

Comment: May I know if there is name to write such style ? Then I may take a further look on it

Comment: @AeLeung It's just called [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) (this is the pattern that React is based on). This is a specific instance of a [higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function).

Comment: Oh , I thought it is related to the concept of closure. Since the "id" is blinded to the returned function

Answer (score 1):

Use `data` and `setData` inside **Child.jsx**, otherwise you can not have infinite childs.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

export const Child = (props) => {

const [data, setData] = useState(props.initialData);


  return <>
  
  <h1>This is {data}</h1>
  <input value={data} onChange={((e)=>setData(e.target.value))}></input>
  
  </>
}
```

Now, inside your **App.jsx**:

```
    const [childs, setChilds] = useState([]);

return (    

    <button onClick={() => setChilds([...childs, {data: {`child${childs.length}`, showChild: true} }])}>add child</button>

    {
    childs.length &&
    childs.map(child => {
        if(child.showChild){
            return (
                <Child initialData={child.data} />
                <button onClick={() => {let newChildsArray = childs.forEach(item =>{if(item.data === child.data){child.showChild = false}} ) setChilds(newChildsArray)}}>show {child.data}</button>
            )
        }
    }

)
```

Some of the concepts I used here was Rest Operator, Literal function, and Controlled Component, if you want to search further.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, actually this is what I have through about and almost solved my question. However, there is one big problem. It's the showChild. If I put data (creating data state inside child) , then whenever the show child condition change from false to true.... all data will be gone when the child show up again

Comment: In fact, inside child, it may have more data input fields...its just simplified

Comment: No problem, see my edited awnser.

Comment: you edited? seems to be same

Comment: I was editing, check it now.

Comment: may I ask could you explain what you are doing here ? if(child.data === child.data)? Or it would be better if you could explain a bit more on the onclick click back function?

Comment: I ended up using the same var name, i changed it. Lets say this is the button for the first child, child.data will be child1, if child1 === item.data, we set this item showChild to false. And then we update the state, causing a re-render.

Comment: Thanks, somehow I understand....may I ask, if it is possible to use rest operator to make that callback function cleaner?

Comment: At the very beginning, you mentioned to use create a useState approach in child. May I know if it is possible that we use redux appraoach and passing set state function into child componment, while keeping it not to lose it all data when condition change from false to true

Comment: Redux would add too much complexity. If you want to pass a function into a child component, must use props instead. You only have 2 components, even if you have more, and need a global state, Context API would be an best solution.

Comment: Thanks for further explanation, May I know, if there is a similar case that use useContext , then I may take a reference in future about how to make use of it. Or simply how to change the style from above to use useContext

Answer (score 0):

The better approach for this type of problem is not to use separate `useState` for every child.

But, to use one `useState` which itself is an `array of objects`.
For this, you can add and manipulate as per your required wish.

Comment: I heard use context seems to be doable, is it possible to use usecontext to achieve my goal in this case?

Comment: useContext is mainly used for state management throughout the app.
For app of this small scale, I do not think it is appropriate for this case.

Comment: May I know, if there is a similar case that use useContext , then I may take a reference in future